# Wrapping a component with itself in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a component named **Match** (renders `span`) and a string like `Matched text` to be wrapped with that component.

I'm expecting a final result like this:

```
<Match>Matched <Match>text</Match></Match>
```

On first wrap, my source text turns into a component like this:

```
<Match>Matched text</Match>
```

With this, is it possible wrap the inside of it (the `text` part) with another **Match** component? What should be the approach here?

Thanks.

Comment: I would think your expected result would throw an error in JSX, seeing as you have improperly nested tags.

Comment: @djfdev sorry forgot to add but component renders a span, and having span inside span should be valid?

Answer (score 0):

It should work just right. Is it what you are looking for?

```js
class Match extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (this.props.children === 'text') {
            return (
                <span style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>{this.props.children}</span>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <span style={{ color: 'blue' }}>{this.props.children}</span>
            )
        }
    }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  matchString(string) {
    /* you can work with the raw string here if you want */
    return string.split(' ')
      .map(word => <Match>{word}</Match>);
      
      /* inside the map you can do whatever you want here, maybe conditional wrapping, like if(word === 'text') <Match>word</Match> else word ... */
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.matchString('Matched text')}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<body id="root">
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, but I won't be rendering all at once. First, it would be "Matched <Match>text</Match>" . Then I need to wrap "Matched text". Or vice-versa.

The problem is, once I do one, I am losing the matching text I am looking for, because it's wrapped in an element.

Comment: I updated my code snippet above, please take a look and LMK if that is what you are looking for since I don't think I understand it clearly yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is ofcourse possible, each instance of the `Match` is different and whatever you write between `Match` tags are the children of the match component. So you just need

```js
class Match extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <span>{this.props.children}</span>
        )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Match>Matched <Match>text</Match></Match>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Please see the comment above.